# mysql regular expression matching query

Tags: mysql

Is this both query are similar? or which query is best to use.

```
SELECT name FROM employees WHERE skill_sets REGEXP '[[:<:]]php[[:>:]]'

SELECT name FROM employees WHERE skill_sets LIKE '%php%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see a article :

http://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/mysql-query-speed-regexp-vs-like/

> If you just need fast, ‘any character’
>   pattern matching though, **LIKE** is your
>   friend.